# Nginx connection refused while connecting to the local process

Tags: docker, nginx, networking, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm testing reverse proxy server with Nginx docker container.

```
docker run -it --rm --name proxy \
        -v $PWD/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf \
        --network host \
        nginx:1.25.3
```

```
# nginx.conf
server {
    listen 8080;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:80;
    }
}
```

And there is another nginx docker container listening 80 port.

```
docker run -it --rm --name nginx \
        --network host \
        nginx:1.25.3
```

The problem is if cURL request is sent from outside of containers, returns the following error:

```
> curl localhost:8080
<html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.25.3</center>
</body>
</html>
```

```
# nginx log
2024/01/24 02:55:51 [error] 71#71: *7 connect() to 127.0.0.1:9080 failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:9080/", host: "localhost:8080"
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Jan/2024:02:55:51 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "curl/8.0.1" "-"
2024/01/24 02:55:51 [info] 71#71: *7 client 127.0.0.1 closed keepalive connection
```

Even though, cURL request from inside of proxy container works well.

```
> curl localhost:80
...
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
...
```

I have no idea why this weird error happens. And even I don't know I do how investigate the reason of this.

This is the environment I am using.

```
> cat /etc/os-release
NAME="SLES"
VERSION="15-SP4"
VERSION_ID="15.4"
PRETTY_NAME="SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 15 SP4"
...
```

Comment: Why are you disabling Docker networking for these containers?  Does the second port 9080 appear anywhere in your configuration?